# Eliminar valores duplicados Array de arrays

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

Tengo un array de este estilo

```javascript
[
  ["16/02/2020"],
  ["16/02/2020"],
  ["17/02/2020"],
  ["17/02/2020"],
  ["18/07/2020"]
]
```

con valores repetidos, lo que quiero es quedarme unicamente con los valores unicos, se que con `...new Set` se puede hacer, pero solo lo he conseguido dejando los arrays de dentro como strings `(["16/02/2020","16/02/2020","17/02/2020","17/02/2020","18/07/2020"])`

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El `Set` no te esta funcionando porque tenes un arreglo de arreglos de strings. El `Set` evalúa los repetidos de cada array interno por ende, nunca quita duplicados porque no los hay.

Para que te funcione debes tener un solo arreglo con los string y luego con [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) cargarlo a un `Set` el cual te hará el remove automático de duplicados:

```js
    let list = ["16/02/2020", "16/02/2020", "17/02/2020", "17/02/2020", "18/07/2020"];
    
    let uniq = [...new Set(list)];
    
    uniq.forEach((x) => {
        console.log(x);
    })
```

Podes probar el código en el playground de TS https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

*El spread funciona a partir de typescript version +3.7*

Comment: el spread es de Javascript, Typescript solo es un framework

Comment: Así es Jack, TS es un superset de javascript, perdón por no aclarar.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Typescript no es un framework, prácticamente es un lenguaje(fuertemente tipado) que compila a javascript.

Comment: Difiero de tu comentario @DavElsanto de igual forma podemos debatir esto en el [chat] este no es el lugar para hacerlo

Comment: Ok, crea el room

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que usar `Set` es una buena idea, solo faltaría que ese `set` lo conviertas en un array, y la forma mas sencilla es `[...el_set]` lo que complica un poco es el formato de los datos originales por que es un array de arrays. Dejo dos opciones, una con `set` y otra con `reduce` e `includes`. Para mantener el formato original en la respuesta se puede hacer `.map(e=>[e])`

```js
const arr = [["16/02/2020"],["16/02/2020"],["17/02/2020"],["17/02/2020"],["18/07/2020"]];

let dist = new Set();

arr.forEach(e=>dist.add(e[0]));// <-- agregamos el elemento 0 de cada array

dist = [...dist].map(e=>[e]);

const dist2 = arr.reduce((p,c)=>{
                  if (!p.includes(c[0])) p.push(c[0]);
                  return p
                  },[]).map(e=>[e]);

console.log(dist);
console.log(dist2);
```